# Adding 'Share This' converts webpage to strange characters

Tags: html

Please refer to the following webpage.

http://www.periodafterpregnancy.net/

As you can see, the information in the text is in a strange encoding. It wasn't like this before I added the share buttons at the top of the page. If I take away the code for the share this buttons namely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "4862c692-7e26-4a83-a907-    
78a57f475e46", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

in the  tags.

and

```
<span class='st_sharethis' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_email' displayText='Email'></span> 
<span class='st_fblike' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
<span class='st_plusone' displayText='Google +1'></span>
```

then the text appears as normal.....as soon as I put this code in, the strange characters appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

P.S: Actually, even if I take way the code after I've added it in, the strange characters still appear....

Comment: Looks like the underlying html has been "changed". If you don't have your original text anywhere, you could always pull it back from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130409172412/http://periodafterpregnancy.net

Comment: Looks like it is fixed now, care to share your fix? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to fix this, I just added the following line to the first meta element of my  tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```